# Como Cadastrar uma data no meu Banco de dados usando ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Vamos supor que eu quero cadastrar um item no meu banco de dados.sabendo que meu item nome e preço.Mas quero também quando registrar o item deve registrar também a data.como faço isso?Ainda sou novo em Asp.net Mvc

```
MODEL
     public class TABLE
        {
            [Key]
            public int IdApp { get; set; }
            public string AppName { get; set; }
            public DateTime Data { get; set; }
            public int Size { get; set; }
            public double Price { get; set; }
            public byte[] FotoByte { get; set; }
            [NotMapped]
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "O Campo da foto está Vazio")]
            public HttpPostedFileBase foto { get; set; }

        }
```

VIEW

```
@model Store.Models.CadastroApp.TABLE

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "RecordApp";
}
<link href="~/Content/css/RecordApp/index.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h2>App Register</h2><br />
            <div class="">
               @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.AppName, new  {@class="form-control",@placeholder="informa o nome do App" })<br />
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.Price,new  { @class = "form-control",@placeholder="informa o preço"})<br />
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.foto, new { type = "file" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.foto)
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você quer a data do momento do cadastro? Se for isto você pode fazer direto no seu `INSERT`, mantenha a propriedade Data como você já possui para retornar os dados.

```
SQL Server - INSERT INTO TABELA (Data) Values (GETDATE());
Oracle - INSERT INTO TABELA (Data) Values (SYSDATE());
MySQL - INSERT INTO TABELA (Data) Values (NOW());
```

Comment: Sim quero que ele me registra direito a data no momento do cadastro.Do jeito você explicou fica meio com fuso,pois no caso estou usando entity.

Comment: Então neste caso, na ActionResult que vai realizar o cadastro vc atribui TABLE. Data =  = DateTime.Now; antes de executar o método save.

Comment: Valeu @Alexsandro.foi útil a sua reposta